# Datatables: Button for Showing Photo for Each Filename

Tags: ajax, button, datatables

I am very new to Datatables and this might be simple, but surely I am missing something. I am trying to create a button column that uses the filename of each row  and uses it to make an ajax call to display a picture on click. What I get wrong is that, every button of the column displays the same image, and not the image of the filename for each row. Here is the code:

$.ajax ({
            url: "http:// ...... /Services/DBPrintDatatable?customer_id=" + projectid,

```
        type: "GET",

        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,

        success: function(data) {
            $('#projectsdt').show();    
            projectsTable = $('#projectsdt').DataTable({
              "pageLength": 10, 
              "data": data, 
              "scrollX": true,
              "aaSorting": [],
              "columns": [ 
                { "data": "upload_date" },
                { "data": "filename" },
                { "data": "uploader" },    
                { "data": "upload_place" },    
                { "data": "is_ok" },
                { "data": "custom_verdict" },
                {
                      data: { "data": "filename" },
                      render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return "<a data-fancybox='gallery' class='btn btn-success' href='http://......./Services/DBShowImage?filename='+ { 'data': 'filename' }>Show</a>";
                      }
                },
              ] , 


            });
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the image url required is like

http://......./Services/DBShowImage?filename=filenameFromData
Then you should generate it first inside the render like below code

href='http://......./Services/DBShowImage?filename="+ row.filename+"';

```
   render: function ( data, type, row ) {
          return "<a data-fancybox='gallery' class='btn btn-success' href='http://......./Services/DBShowImage?filename="+ row.filename+"'>Show</a>";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and unfortunately I get the same result as before...

Comment: use row.filename for getting filename, if the key for the file name is 'filename'

Comment: Please refer example from this link https://ideoplex.com/2014/10/23/datatables-column-render/